# When calling tf.Session.run, is it important for performance to minimize what is fetched?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, the `fetches` argument to `tf.Session.run` serves two purposes: it ensures that certain ops are run, and it returns values to python.  My question is how concerned I need to be to avoid returning values I don't actually need.  For instance, suppose that op `a` depends on op `b` so that if `a` is evaluated `b` will be too.  Could it be faster to do

```
a = sess.run([a])
```

than to do

```
a, _ = sess.run([a,b])
```

because the latter would copy the output of `b` from the GPU to the CPU only for it to be discarded?  If only a fraction of the information in `a` is needed on the python side, is it generally a good practice to make a tensor depending on `a` that only has exactly what is needed and to fetch that instead of `a`?  Or am I misunderstanding something about how these GPU-CPU transfers work?  I think it is possible to profile how much time is spent in transfers like these (e.g., see graphs here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4526), but I don't understand how to do it yet, and I would like to know if I am at least conceptualizing things correctly regardless of whether my particular application happens to be bottlenecked here.

Comment: You can run `a.op` instead of `a` to have the operation execute, but not fetch its value into Python (you get `None`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is relatively important, because the python wrapper has to convert from the C++ tensor memory to the python numpy array, thus doing a copy operation. If you are fetching big Variables the time could be not trivial, think of 1GB having to be converted each time.